# How to cut thick felt carpet pad?

Tags: tools, carpet, technique, cutting, hand-tools

We are installing carpeting and purchased felt pad for it.  Using a utility knife, though, even changing the blades frequently, we are having a really hard time cutting it.

Is there a tool, technique, or better knife/blade that we should be using for felt carpet padding?

Comment: How thick is it?  Do you have a pair of utility snips, like the kind for cutting metal?

Comment: I don't have it at hand, but it is pretty thick - maybe 7/16".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up trying a carpet knife, and it worked perfectly. I'm not sure why it would cut when the utility knife wouldn't, perhaps just the longer length of expose blade did the trick, or perhaps my utility blades weren't very sharp.

I also used a board underneath and pressed firmly, but it was still much better than the utility knife, industrial scissors, serrated knife, and all the other methods I tried.

Also came in very handy for trimming the carpet later.

[image: harbor freight "pivoting carpet knife". Double edged blade in yellow handle with bend in handle to present blade at a 20-30 degree angle. Blade is removable, but does not retract.]

Answer (score 2):

Take a 2x4 or other long straight edge, and stand on it to compress the pad and stabilize it, then use your utility knife to cut it.

Comment: Make sure you're working with a sharp blade (change blades as necessary), and be prepared to make a second pass with the blade if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing a lot of carpet/flooring work, get yourself a hooked flooring/carpet knife (any hardware store will have them). They have a large hooked blade and a good solid handle. Remember to keep body parts out of the "line of fire". #1 workplace injury: utility knife vs. body part.

Answer (score 1):

You might laugh, but I use a very sharp BREAD knife on certain types of soundproofing/wool insulation (ROXUL) and it slices it like butter.  You might try something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I use a carpet cutter from  roberts, its a red handle carpet cutter for cutting carpet  with pad attached. The blade is adjustable for different sizes.  I do this every day as I work in flooring